# Token in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, token, core-text

I want to recreate this token in my `UITableViewCell`. I want it to be so if it detects something with an `@` in the `cell.textLabel.text` string using Regex. It will automatically highlight that with a token like the one below.

Also it should be tappable.

[image: I want to create something like this!]

Answer (score 1):

Use CoreText to determine the bounding box and then use that information while drawing the cell's view.

Comment: I added some new code using your suggestion, but i get an error message, which I don't understand. Any ideas?